# Remove section numbering in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I started numbering a document after two sections, and want them to be removed from the TOC.

what I have is the following:
[image]

I would like to obtain:

[image]

this is the latex script I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[top=0.59in,bottom=0.59in,left=0.59in,right=0.59in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\section*{Abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Some text
\newpage
\section*{List of abbreviations}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Some text
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{figure}{0} \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{table}{0} \renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section*{Introduction}
Some text
\section*{Goals}
Some text
\end{document}
```

thank you

Comment: Hi, please post a MWE that illustrates your problem.

Comment: You should offer us a mwe or at least your `documentclass`. Otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: What about using `\section*{}`?

Comment: Added MWE in the question, cheers

Comment: Why `xcolor` and `color`? Why not loading `hyperref` at the end of the preamble?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I removed some unrelevant things from the mwe

Comment: @jarhead: Yes, but your document still does not show the problem. There are no section numbers in the ToC!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I don't mind the section numbers, I just want to remove the specific section from the TOC

Comment: Just as in the photos I added

Comment: @jarhead: Please read the title of your post: **Remove section numbering in the ToC** ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently some sections should not appear in the ToC (and not removing the section numbers), so use the `\tocdepth@munge` and `\tocdept@restore` commands, written to the `ToC`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[top=0.59in,bottom=0.59in,left=0.59in,right=0.59in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\tocdepth@munge}
\section*{Abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Some text
\clearpage
\section*{List of abbreviations}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\tocdepth@restore}
\makeatother
Some text
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{figure}{0} \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{table}{0} \renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
%\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Goals}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]